# how to get table object using cssclass selector?

Tags: jquery

I have an HTML page with lot of tables. Among that I have a table with the following format

```
<table><tr><td class="myclass">..</td></tr>
<tr><td class="myclass">..</td></tr></table>
```

How can I get the object of this table using the class selector in jquery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the parents() method. This allows you to traverse up the DOM tree. You can pass the method a selector to filter results.

```
 $("td.myclass").parents("table");
```

In my opinion, this is the neatest way of achieving what you need. The documentation is here: http://api.jquery.com/parents/

Answer (score 2):

You'd get the table using `$('table')` or the table cells using `$('table td.myClass')`.

If you want to get the table based on the class of its cells, you'd use `$('table').has('td.myClass')`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var mytable = $('td.myclass').parent().parent();
```

or

```
var mytable = $('td.myclass:parent').parent();
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't get the table object with this structure using a class selector. If you want to apply a class selector on a table object then you have to give the table a class name.

```
<table class="tblclass"><tr><td class="myclass">..</td></tr>
<tr><td class="myclass">..</td></tr></table>
```

and CSS

```
table.tblclass 
{
}
```

The below one is not a class selector for the table but it will find the table closest to the td element with class name myclass.

```
$("td.myclass").closest("table");
```